# add filter login_redirect does not contain original requested redirect

Tags: filters, hooks, login, actions

I link to WP's login page passing: redirect_to=play

...ttp://www.my.com/wp-login.php/?**redirect_to=play**">Click here...

I use the value (in this case: play) as a flag, not an actual redirect url, because I intercept the redirect request using:

```
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user)
{
    var_dump($redirect_to);
    var_dump($requested_redirect_to);
    var_dump($user);
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
```

Expected result: $requested_redirect_to would contain the value: play. However, wp login does not relay the original redirect_to value, in fact no mater what I do, the 2 params $requested_redirect_to and $redirect_to are always empty; only $user contains data.

How do I pass my original redirect_to value all the way through the login process and into the filter: login_redirect?

Comment: i tried your code and i see `play` in `$redirect_to`. it can be other plugins that change this value with filter. try to change the priority to `-10` e.g.

Comment: mmm, thank you for looking at this.  I lowered the priority. Same result.  To be clear: array(1) { ["redirect_to"]=> string(4) "play" }  does appear on the login page. However, login form submission does not relay the value back to the WP filter: login_redirect; login_redirect does fire, but the parameters are now empty.

Comment: Are the parameters sent at all (check your browser's dev tools)? Does `var_dump($_REQUEST)` contain them?

Comment: I found the problem : you forget to return `$redirect_to` in your code then the URL is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use login_redirect filter. See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

I think this is what you are looking for.

This will normally redirect all logins. To be able to redirect only when you want, you can use a query string parameter in the URL. Check for the parameter, if it exists redirect.

Try to add this in your template functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'login_form' , 'glue_login_redirect' );
function glue_login_redirect() {
    global $redirect_to;
    if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
        $redirect_to = 'YOURURLHERE';
    }
    else{
        $redirect_to = $_GET['redirect_to'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I was using the wrong hook, login_form with a global var is the fix.  Thank you Dharmishtha.